# How to store ascii characters in Oracle and display them correctly in a webpage?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, web-applications, ascii

We data-drive some text in our database, such as names of products, etc. Recently our marketing team asked us to display product names with special characters such as the registered trademark symbol ®, ascii code 174.

My question is, how can we best store this character in our data, so that it displays correctly in both HTML and non-HTML formats? At first, we tried something like this:

```
update products_table set display_name = 'FooCorp' || chr(174) || ' Awesome Product' where product_id = 1;
```

When I query that product in TOAD, the registered trademark symbol shows up correctly, but when we try and query and display that text in our webapp, neither Firefox nor IE knows how to display it. Both show the "diamond with a ?" symbol instead.

Next, we did this:

```
update products_table set display_name = 'FooCorp&#174 Awesome Product' where product_id = 1;
```

... which makes our webapp happy, but of course anything non-HTML that tries to show a products list (ex: SQL queries that generate reports) now show the HTML character in the name.

Anyone have any ideas on how we can satisfy both the HTML and non-HTML world? Ideally we'd like to avoid having separate columns that duplicate the text, but if that's really the only way, we can go that route.

Comment: What is the database character set (I'm assuming `display_name` is a `VARCHAR2`)?  What is the character set of the web page?

Comment: The database character set appears to be: WE8ISO8859P1, while the page encoding for our web page is UTF-8. This might be the issue, I'll have to see if we can somehow make those match.

Comment: You don't necessarily need (or want) them to match.  You do, however, need for character set conversion to take place at some point.  The Oracle client will happily convert data from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 if the client `NLS_LANG` is set properly.  Where is your data getting converted from the database character set to the web page's character set?

Comment: Just for your future reference, there is no such thing as ASCII code 174. ASCII only goes up to 127. There are various ASCII-compatible 8-bit encodings of which ISO-8859-1 is one. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#8-bit

Comment: Justin: that's a very good question and the answer is that I don't know yet. :) The application is using JDBC to query the database. Could you (or someone) post how we might do the character set conversion on the Java side, or ask the oracle client to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Well, chr(174) may mean smth in Oracle but when it comes to web browsers they may have diff char. settings etc... I'm not sure but maybe you simply hardcode that character to your query:

```
    SELECT 'FooCorp® Awesome Product' FROM dual;
```